# Can't run android on windows to start reactNative app

Tags: react-native, java-home

I have just started learning *reactNative*, I was able to set up *reactNative* via command line on *Windows*, but I could nott start Android emulator.

[image]

Any idea on what am I missing here?

Comment: Have you set JAVA_HOME? Also, please include error messages and other content in the question, not as pictures.

Comment: i have set JAVA_HOME:"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181" into System Variables and add %JAVA_HOME%\bin into Path, but this still show error as picture above

Comment: type `javac` and press enter button, See if javac execute successfully or not

Comment: I'm really sorry for reply later, My issue has been solved. In path of Environment variables, i added C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin in to it